# Load Excel file with UNIX OS using odi

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

i have multiple excel file along with multiple sheet in each excel file. i have odi install on UNIX operating system. With windows we can directly create ODBC connection & pass it on Physical schema. What if we have UNIX system. Problem statement : I have converted the excel file into csv with unix script but most of the columns present in excel have string values 
[image]

This is how we can't differentiate comma which is used in string and column separation.

Any idea how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

My approach has always been to convert the Excel file to CSV using a PERL script. This can be triggered in ODI using an ODI Tool OdiOsCommand.

I think I used this one which allows a lot of parameters : https://metacpan.org/pod/release/KEN/xls2csv-1.07/script/xls2csv

This one looks good as well : https://github.com/soh-i/Excel2CSV